# I got stuck at "Enter a string:" and doesn't take any input-8086 programming

Tags: masm, x86-16, emu8086

In the program for to find out no. of vowels in a string. I got stuck at "Enter a string:" ?? why? even tho the compiler says everything okay.

program to count the no. of vowels in a string.

```
;;;;;;;PROGRAM TO CHECK NO. OF VOWELS IN A STRING;;;;;
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
vowels db 'AEIOUaeiou$'
msg1 db 'Enter a string:$'
msg2 db 'The string is:$'
msg3 db 'No of vowels are:$'
string db 50 dup('$')
count db ?
.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
lea dx,msg1
mov ah,09h             ;for displaying enter a string
int 21h
lea di,string
cld
xor bl,bl
input:mov ah,01         ; stuck here, at taking input, why??
cmp al, 13
je endinput
stosb
inc bl
jmp input
endinput:cld
xor bh,bh
lea si,string
vowelornot: mov cx,11
lodsb
lea di,vowels
repne scasb
cmp cx, 00
je stepdown
inc bh
stepdown: dec bl
jnz vowelornot
mov ah,06                ;;;THIS FOR CLEARING SCREEN I GUESS
mov al,0                  ;;;
int 10h
lea dx,msg2
mov ah,09
int 21h
mov dl, 13                  ;;; NEW LINE
mov ah, 2
int 21h
mov dl, 10
mov ah, 2
int 21h
lea dx,string
mov ah, 09
int 21h
mov dl,13                   ;;;NEW LINE
mov ah,2
int 21h
mov dl,10
mov ah,2
int 21h
lea dx, msg3
mov ah,09
int 21h
mov dl,13                  ;;;NEW LINE
mov ah,2
int 21h
mov dl,10
mov ah,2
int 21h
mov count, bh
mov dh, count                   ;;; DH = VOWEL COUNT
mov ah,09
int 21h
mov ah, 4ch                            ;;; EXIT
int 21h
main endp
end
```

Comment: There's an `int 21h` missing to invoke the ah=1 function.

Comment: thanks, umhm exactly. but, i still can't get the vowels count, wheres the problem, can you correct me.

Comment: Finally made this working..... 
I didn't know a lot of things here
had to change these ....

````
add bh, 48          ;;; to make number to ascii;;;;
mov dl, bh  
mov ah, 2             ;;;no i get the real count of vowel. yess;;;;
int 21h
``````

Comment: I can't make this post "Answered"? @HansPassant ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Multiple errors

> ```
> input:mov ah,01         ; stuck here, at taking input, why??
> cmp al, 13
> ```

Here your code is missing the `int 21h` instruction!

```
input:
 mov ah,01
 int 21h
 cmp al, 13
```

---

> ```
>  xor bl,bl
> input:
>
>  stosb
>  inc bl
>  jmp input
> ```

You're using `BL` to count the number of characters in the input string **but the example you wrote needs much more than the 255 maximum that this *byte-sized* register can give you**. This must fail!

Moreover the buffer that you've setup is limited to 50 bytes. No way you could store there such a long input.

---

> ```
> lea si,string
> vowelornot: mov cx,11
> lodsb
> lea di,vowels
> repne scasb
> cmp cx, 00
> je stepdown
> inc bh
> stepdown: dec bl
> jnz vowelornot
> ```

This is too complicated. Just interpret the ZeroFlag and don't look at `CX` at all. You don't need to terminate the *vowels* text with a "$" anymore (use `CX=10`).

```
 lea si,string
vowelornot:
 lodsb
 mov cx,10
 lea di,vowels
 repne scasb
 jne stepdown
 inc bh        ;Vowel found +1
stepdown:
 dec bl
 jnz vowelornot
```

---

> ```
> mov ah,06                ;;;THIS FOR CLEARING SCREEN I GUESS
> mov al,0                  ;;;
> int 10h
> ```

Sure, function 06h can clear the screen but you need to provide all of the required arguments. Upperleftcorner in `CX`, Lowerrightcorner in `DX` and Displaypage in `BH`.

```
mov dx, 184Fh   ;(79,24) If screen is 80x25
xor cx, cx      ;(0,0)
mov bh, 0
mov ax, 0600h
int 10h
```

---

> ```
> lea dx,string
> mov ah, 09
> int 21h
> ```

This will fail because you did not put a "$" character at the end of the inputted string.
And if you're going to output a CRLF directly afterwards, why not add it to the buffer?

```
 jmp input
endinput:
 mov ax, 0A0Dh  <-- ADD THIS
 stosw          <-- ADD THIS
 mov al, "$"    <-- ADD THIS
 stosb          <-- ADD THIS

 xor bh,bh
```

---

You print *msg2* and *msg3* followed by a CRLF. Why don't you append it in the definition? No more need to output it separately.

```
msg2 db 'The string is:', 13, 10, '$'
msg3 db 'No of vowels are:', 13, 10, '$'
```

---

> ```
> mov count, bh
> mov dh, count                   ;;; DH = VOWEL COUNT
> mov ah,09
> int 21h
> ```

To output the count **and provided it is a number in the range from 0 to 9**, you need to convert the number into a character. Just add 48 or '0'.
Don't use function 09h. It requires an **address** and you clearly want to use a **character**.

```
mov dl, bh    ;Count of vowels [0,9]
add dl, '0'
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying.